# Centering a div on a VERY SIMPLE PAGE

Tags: css, html, center

Yes. This has been asked a billion times. But nobody has given an answer that works for me.

It's so stupid. I have a SPLASH PAGE.. which has almost NO code on it. All it has is some js and a series of photos that fade in, one by one.

No matter what i do, it aligns top left of the screen. Here's the code.

```
<div style="height:100%; width=100%; margin: 0px auto;" id="these">
    <img src="photos/splash/Y.png" height="250px" style="padding: 20px;">
    <img src="photos/splash/I.png" height="250px" style="padding: 20px;">
    <img src="photos/splash/K.png" height="250px" style="padding: 20px;">
    <img src="photos/splash/M.png" height="250px" style="padding: 20px;">
    <img src="photos/splash/U.png" height="250px" style="padding: 20px;">
    <img src="photos/splash/N.png" height="250px" style="padding: 20px;">
</div>
```

I want it to align in the very center of any screen, regardless of resolution. ID="these" is related to the javascript that displays them and not to any css-level styles or positioning.

Ridiculously simple right?? Yeah. It's always showing up on the top left.

I don't feel it's necessary to post the js (also it's breaking my post) but if you want it, ask. It works fine. I'm a backend coder who HATES (as in detests) HTML/CSS. So you'll have to really walk me through it and not just make vague suggestions.

I even tried a table! With a valign center. That centered it but each image showed up in the center and then was pushed left as the next image faded in. Obviously not what i want.

What i want is for each image to show up, one after the other, in it's own position. But will work for any screen resolution.

I'm losing my mind.

Thanks.

Comment: post your code on JSFiddle.com and link it here.

Comment: Isn't one of your images missing the "src" keyword?

Comment: To use `margin:0 auto` you must have a **fixed width**.

Comment: Vucko, my body tag has a fixed width of 100% - the thing is, I can create a new div that restricts the width but i really want it to center in any screen resolution. 

I guess i really don't get positioning.

Comment: doitlikejustin - yeah it didn't post at first. I see it now though.. after a few refreshes. Can you see it?

Comment: Here is my body tag... <body style="background-color:#000000;height: 100%;" width="100%">

Comment: @EllaSilver put something like `<div style="height:100%; width:300px; margin: 0px auto;" id="these">`.

Comment: Ah.. just make the div the width of the combined sum of the images width?

Comment: Yes.  Set a width equal to the total width of all images + any margin, padding, border etc.  But that will only fix your horizontal centering when using `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows you centering inline elements within a block level element.  So all you need to do is this:

```
these { text-align:center; }
```

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/87zqf/

If you want to center the div within its parent, that div must have some width less than 100%.  For example:

```
div#these { 
    width: 350px; 
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/nRKYV/

Comment: Hey Katie K. Yup I tried that. And.. well someone else suggested it too so see the answer i gave to Adam Hart.

Comment: Sooo, is there a slide show moving these things around? Can you provide a demo for us to work on?

Comment: Hi KatieK. Actually i'm about to load the site onto the server so I'll provide a link in about 5 minutes.

Comment: @Ella - I might have time to look, but small self-contained examples (just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra) work best. Post this code into the question - so that it's useful to the next person. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: Is the code still not showing up in the question for you Katie? I am seeing it now (when i first posted the question it wasn't visible but became visible after a few refreshes)

Comment: @EllaSilver - I can see your div and images in your question, but I don't see any JS. If the JS **isn't** affecting the layout, then there should be no differences between your stuff and the examples I provided in the JSfiddles.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some other css that'll mess this up, just add

```
#these {
    text-align: center;
}
```

to the div wrapper and toggle visibility on/off to keep them in place: http://jsfiddle.net/63cHS/

Comment: Hey Adam Hart - Yup, that centers  it but the problem is that when one image comes in, it then shifts to the left to allow the next image to come in at the center.. and so on. 

I'd like them to already know their end positions as they fade in.

Comment: Updated my answer with display: block images, which is what you might be looking for

Comment: sweet. Here's the page. Here is how it is currently rendering. And if you view source, obviously you can see all the code. The splash is the only page up now since it's the only buggy item left. http://yikmunphotography.com/indexSplash2.html

Comment: So it turns out that the client LIKES the bug and in the interest of meeting the deadling, we're going with it. 

However... i know this issue drives people absolutely insane. So a discussion can't hurt.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now, it's because you're toggling "display: none" to "display: inline" as it loads.  "display: none" removes the element from the layout, causing your centered wrapper div to be smaller.  You can toggle "visibility: hidden" to "visibility: visible" instead, and leave it display inline to keep the characters in position.

Answer (score 0):

100% height on a div will not work, which is one of the shortcomings of CSS (in my opinion).

In the end, it can only be done if you know the height of your `<div>`. What you want to do then is to position it absolutely, 50% off the top and left of your screen and with a margin of half its height/width.

Check out the following JSFiddle for an idea of how it can be done:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lsh6j/1/

Note that you could also use percentages for the height and width on the surrounding `<div>`, but for the percentage-based height to work, the `<div>`'s parent element's height must be set/known.

Comment: uweB will this work on various resolutions? This might be a good solution.

Comment: Yes it should. If you click the link in my posting above, try resizing your browser and/or the "sub-windows" of JSFiddle. The box will stay centered within its boundaries.

Comment: 100% height will work on almost anything if the parent element has the explicit height. To keep 100% of the viewport height, you have to set `height: 100%` for all ancestors of the element, including the root element (`html`).

Answer (score 0):

Using this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/) as a guideline. **First** add a `centered` class with this css.

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; 
 }
```

**Add** this class to your div:

```
<div class="centered" id="these">
  ...images....
</div>
```

The problem is this centers the top left of the div. So you need to subtract off half of the `width` from the `margin-left` and half of the `height` from the `margin-top`.

**Add** this javascript (uses jQuery, let me know if thats a problem) to do the adjustment

```
<script>

function adjust() {
    var height = $("#these").height();
    var width = $("#these").width();
    $("#these").css("margin-top", "-" + height/2 + "px"); 
    $("#these").css("margin-left", "-" + width/2 + "px"); 
}
$(window).on("resize", adjust);
adjust();
```

This sets the margins appropriately on a resize, as well as calls the `adjust` method on the initial load.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFKG6/1/)):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* necessary to make the window height be 100% */
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#these {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; /* for table cells, it aligns their content */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Another option ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFKG6/)):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* necessary to make the window height be 100% */
    margin: 0;
}

#these {
    text-align: center; /* images are text content */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#these:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block; /* adding invisible inline placeholder after images */
    height: 100%; /* make it 100% tall */
    vertical-align: middle; /* and align the whole line to its vertical center */
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle; /* align vertical centers of images to the middle of the line  */
}
```